# Removing key from associative array

Tags: php, arrays, key, unset

I would like to remove a certain value based on the value. Example in this situation, I would like to remove `Tom` from the array, then the next data will continue with the number that is previously used by `Tom`.

Here's my example:

```
    $array = array(0 => "Emily", 1 => "Tom", 2 => "Peter");
    if ($k = array_search($csR, $array)!==false)
            unset($array[$k]);
```

The outcome should be:

```
array(0 => "Emily", 1 => "Peter");
```

Comment: Use array_values to "fix" the keys.

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using an indexed array, the best way to achieve this is to use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$csR = 'Tom';
$array = array(0 => "Emily", 1 => "Tom", 2 => "Peter");
if ($k = array_search($csR, $array)!==false)
{
    unset($array[$k]);
    $array = array_values($array);
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the documentation of [PHP: Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Note:
The unset() function allows removing keys from an array. Be aware that the array will not be reindexed. If a true "remove and shift" behavior is desired, the array can be reindexed using the array_values() function.

```
<?php
$a = array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three');
unset($a[2]);
/* will produce an array that would have been defined as
   $a = array(1 => 'one', 3 => 'three');
   and NOT
   $a = array(1 => 'one', 2 =>'three');
*/

$b = array_values($a);
// Now $b is array(0 => 'one', 1 =>'three')
?>
```

Comment: May I know is it possible if I would still like to have 3 keys in total after removing that the second key?

Comment: unset will remove the key meaning that you will have one less key. You could add the value back by using something like `$array[3] = 'four'`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the difference between the array and an array with `Tom` or `$csR` and then re-index:

```
$array = array_values(array_diff($array, [$csR]));
```

However, there is rarely a need to have sequential keys.  Have you tried `foreach` instead of `for`?